# How to get counts from AlterRow transformation in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an AlterRow transformation that marks each row with the appropriate CRUD operation in an ADFv2 data flow.  I don't see any output variables on this activity that will give me the total inserts, updates, etc.  I do, however, see methods in the expression syntax to tell me if a particular row is an IsInsert(), IsUpdate(), etc.

Would the correct way to get counts be to

1. Add another output from the AlterRow transformation
2. Add derived column that uses the expression syntax IsInsert(), IsUpdate() to set operation type (I, U, D)
3. Add an aggregate to group by this column to get total counts for each operation

When creating the aggregate, I don't see any metadata that would allow me to group by the CRUD operation type so I assume I would have to create this myself, but it seems like it should already be there since that's the purpose of the AlterRow transformation.  Am I working too hard to get these counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an aggregate after your AlterRow with no group-by and use these formulas:

[image]